# How can I put more space between words?

Tags: support, editing

I find that sometimes I need to put some texts as the following:

> A.x+y   B.2x   C.y+z

Here is my question:

How can one put more spaces between this "choices" when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [html entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for space: `&nsbp;`

So writing
`A. Choice1 &nbsp; B. Choice2 &nbsp; C. Choice3`

will make it look like

A. Choice1   B. Choice2   C. Choice3

When you are editing, look at the top right corner, there you will see a yellow question mark, which has help for formatting.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this would be to put each choice on a new line. The website requires at least two spaces at the end of a line, in addition to the "return" button, in order to make a new line.

For example,  putting two spaces at the end of each line of this input

```
  A. $x+y$  
  B. $2x$  
  C. $y+z$
```

generates

A. $x+y$
B. $2x$
C. $y+z$

Comment: One should mention that the vertical lines need not be there for that to work.

Comment: @Asaf: Good point, I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

Use LaTeX:

> $$ A.\, x+y \qquad B.\, 2x \qquad C.\, y+z $$

Comment: Written as: `A.\, x+y \qquad B.\, 2x \qquad C.\, y+z`. This one can find by right-clicking on the image and clicking "Show Source".

Comment: Right-clicking the image doesn't show me the option "Show Source" And if I use the code mentioned by @ShreevatsaR the LaTeX code does not get formatted in tex.stackexchange.com. How do I tell Stack Exchange to interpret it as LaTeX? Do I need to surround it by $$ or something like this?